# Syntax highlighting for Smalltalk

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I just figured out this meta site could be a good place for asking why Smalltalk syntax is not highlighted in SO (even when tagged)?

I have checked and most fashion programming languages are highlighted, although Smalltalk is (today) not popular or mainstream I think it's a pity one of the most influential programming technologies cannot be highlighted.

Well. It's been 5 years since I've posted this question, still no syntax hightlight as seen in this recent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624366/usage-of-dot-in-smalltalk). Is there any issue tracker where I could migrate the request?

Comment: Smalltalk isn't supported. Ignore the "off-topic" message above, but see [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?: How do I report a bug or request a new language?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/1288)

Comment: Doesn't he need to send you a message?

Comment: Thank you Bill. I've opened an issue https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=352 to request Smalltalk syntax-highlighting.

Comment: So sad, still not supported :(

Comment: Your Google Code issue got moved to https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/352 but so far nobody took on the effort to get this available in Prettify . Until then there is not much you (or SE for that matter) can do .