# Poor syntax hightlighting of Perl code

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

The syntax highlighting in [Script Failure because of Large Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303965/script-failure-because-of-large-arrays) is messed up. Here's a screenshot of the beginning of the poorly highlighted part.

[image]

I'm not surprised that it thinks everything on the line after `$#array` is a comment. It's hard for a simple syntax highlighter to distinguish different uses of `#`. But why is everything after the [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) on the second shown in red? It's stuck like this for most of the rest of the script, but I didn't include it all in the screen shot.

Is this a bug in the syntax highlighting, or a known limitation?

Comment: Bugs with Google Prettify should be reported directly to that project, see the [central FAQ on syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: OK, it looks like this is [bug 57](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=57&q=perl), and the ``$#` problem is [bug 162](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=162&q=perl)

Comment: Right, so these are known issues then (limitations / bugs / unsupported language features / unicorn shortages). :-)

Comment: There are a lot of questions like this on Meta SO for different languages...it's a shame we can't close them as duplicates of the Meta SE FAQ that @MartijnPieters linked to.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: if it is becoming a FAQ here, then we create our own copy on *this* site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Smalltalk](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272327), [Sass](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251334), [Java](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272508)...would it be inappropriate to copy the Meta SE FAQ word for word?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: it's CC licensed, make it a Community Wiki and add a credit. :-) Follow the guidelines on the [FAQ page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) too.